# I don't think it spend that much time (for - if condition checking loops), is there a better way?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I don't think it spend much time, but it takes more than I expected.

I think for - if is the problem.

What makes it takes a lot of times?

Is there a better way to reduce time?

The problem is that

n = number of flowers

a, b = blooming date of flowers (month, date)
c, d = fall date of flowers (month, date)

(When fall date of flowers you can't see that flower)
(if 0530 is fall date, then you can't see that flower on 0530)

I want to see flowers every day from 0301 ~ 1130

Print minimum of needed flowers

I was told that it is greedy algorithm problem.

I don't know how to reduce time anymore

I think it's a proper way to solve this problem

### Here's my code below

```
flo_list = []

n = int(input())

for i in range(n) :
    a, b, c, d = map(int, input().split())
    flo_list.append((a*100 + b, c*100 + d))

flo_list.sort(reverse = True)

cnt = 0

srt_flo = sorted(flo_list, key = lambda i : i[1], reverse = True)

if flo_list[-1][0] > 301 :
    print(0)
    exit()

if srt_flo[0][1] < 1201 :
    print(0)
    exit()

for (i, j) in srt_flo :
    if i <= 301 :
        (f, e) = (i, j)
        cnt = cnt + 1
        break

while e < 1201 :

    for (i, j) in srt_flo :
        if f < i <= e :
            (f, e) = (i, j)
            cnt = cnt + 1
            break

    else :
        cnt = 0
        break


print(cnt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations

for comb_len in range(1,n) :    # `n` -- is the total number of flowers
    for comb in combinations( range(n), comb_len ) :
        if this_combination_covers_all_dates( comb ) :
            print 'need', comb_len, 'flowers', comb
```

The implementation of `this_combination_covers_all_dates( comb )` is up to you =)